# failed while applying security patch SUPEE-6285

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

i got error while applying SUPEE-6285 i saw online that i have to apply SUPEE-5994 and i got this error when i  applied:

```
$ Sh PATCH_SUPEE-5994.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 68 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 113 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 129 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 201 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 272 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 297 (different line endings).
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 273 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 266 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 109 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 190 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 100 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file downloader/Maged/View.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 162 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
checking file downloader/template/messages.phtml
checking file get.php
checking file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
42 out of 42 hunks ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 226 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
```

Comment: probably this happens when you have patches applied many times, or incorrect magento upgrade, version mixed files?

Comment: Witch minor version of Magento 1.9 are you trying to patch?

Comment: i m trying to patch this version Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 6):

> (different line endings)

sounds like your f*cked up your line endings from *nix to Windows.

[You should try `find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929475/1480397) before running the patch again