# Trying to update Magento patches

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, security, patches

I have been trying to apply the latest Magento security patches but I have failed due to the web server where I have the web shop does not allow me to unpack Magento's patches via SSH.

I tried intead to make a copy of the web shop to my local mac along with a database copy and set it up on XAMPP. Could not do that either because the database is around 300Mb big and for some reason it wasn't working even after I changed the max file size and max execution time on the php.ini.

I tried the to update via PHP but then again, I hade the same problem as in the beginning: My web server does not allow me to unpack SSH files.

Last but not least, I tried [this approach](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9) except I did not have any Magento 1.7 but an old Magento 1.9.1.0 contra [a brand new Magento 1.9.2.0 with all the patches already applied](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download). I got as well an error.

Are there any other ways to make the update?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. you want to have a [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) to host your source code
2. you don't want to deploy via FTP/SFTP/SCP/... (at least not file by file)
3. You don't need a database to apply the patch.

Just download all the files and apply the patch. Make sure, that you don't [change the line endings while downloading](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/74947/217)

Comment: Are you telling me that I don't need a DB to update the shop locally? I'm sorry for my ignorance but how do I do that? If I download the shop and run it on my XAMPP in order to apply the patch, won't I need a DB?

Comment: @viriato The patch simply operates on the file system. You never have to "run" Magento in any way. It just makes some changes to various files so the only reason you want the DB also would be to actually run the store after patching to make sure it still works.