# failed while apply patch 8788 v2 it shows error (different line endings)

Tags: magento2, patches

Magento 1.9.0.0 - I have applied patch 3941 and after that, i am trying 8788 v2 but it shows error like below. by the way, I have uploaded the zip file and after unzipping on the server I have applied the patch. but also it shows same.

```
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 34 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 44 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 65 (different line endings).
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 31 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 444 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 31 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 119 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 29 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 373 (offset -19 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 31 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 631 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 269 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 804 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 186 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 25 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 73 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 136 (different line endings).
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 37 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 1289 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 51 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 98 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 65 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 375 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 56 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 163 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 64 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 127 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 32 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 245 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 254 (different line endings).
Hunk #4 FAILED at 273 (different line endings).
4 out of 4 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 32 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 148 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 158 (different line endings).
Hunk #4 FAILED at 171 (different line endings).
4 out of 4 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 152 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 328 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 544 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1258 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 1526 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 70 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 80 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 944 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 1060 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 53 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 58 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 53 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 51 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 54 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 538 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 1037 (different line endings).
```

Answer (score 2):

Referring to this answer here [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74944/failed-while-applying-security-patch-supee-6285) and my experience with the patch it seems like your line endings are broken due to Windows.

Try to run this command

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

then run the patch again